# Text fields reset when I add a new one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form that starts off with one input and then I add additional inputs with the press of a button. However, whenever a new input is added, it clears whatever data was in the previous inputs. Here is what the code looks like:

**Initial input with form:**

```
<form id="grade_inputs" onkeyup="displayGrade()">
    <div class="grade_input">Grade 1: <input class="grade" type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="0"></div>
</form>
```

**The** `displayGrade()` **method:**

```
function displayGrade()
{
var average = calculateAverage();
var grade_label = document.getElementById("grade");
var grade_letter;
var grade_color;

if(average < 70)
{
    grade_letter = "F";
    grade_color = "#E60000";
}
else if(average < 80)
{
    grade_letter = "C";
    grade_color = "#FF7700";
}
else if(average < 90)
{
    grade_letter = "B";
    grade_color = "#FAC800";
}
else
{
    grade_letter = "A";
    grade_color = "#5AE000";
}

grade_label.innerHTML = grade_letter;
grade_label.style.color = grade_color;
}
```

**The function that adds a new input:**

```
function addGrade()
{
var grade_inputs_form = document.getElementById("grade_inputs");

grade_inputs_form.innerHTML += '<div class="grade_input">Grade ' + gradeCounter++ + ': <input class="grade" type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="0"></div>';

displayGrade();
}
```

I'm adding the new inputs by appending to the innerHTML of the parent form. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of going about this, so any recommendations is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: When do you invoke `addGrade` ? What is `calculateAverage` ? Where it is ?

Comment: innerHtml is not working because your changes in textinput  will not affect to DOM. So, when you add new div then your previous value reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead of `innerHTML +=` as it will reinsert entire HTML again which will make you lose the data as well as binded events(Not inline binded events)..

*The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node*

Try this:

```js
var gradeCounter = 2;

function calculateAverage() {
  var average = 0;
  var grades = document.getElementsByClassName("grade");

  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    var gradeNumber = parseInt(grades[i].value);

    if (!isNaN(gradeNumber))
      average += parseInt(grades[i].value);
  }

  return average /= grades.length;
}

function displayGrade() {
  var average = calculateAverage();
  var grade_label = document.getElementById("grade");
  var grade_letter;
  var grade_color;

  if (average < 70) {
    grade_letter = "F";
    grade_color = "#E60000";
  } else if (average < 80) {
    grade_letter = "C";
    grade_color = "#FF7700";
  } else if (average < 90) {
    grade_letter = "B";
    grade_color = "#FAC800";
  } else {
    grade_letter = "A";
    grade_color = "#5AE000";
  }

  grade_label.innerHTML = grade_letter;
  grade_label.style.color = grade_color;
}

function addGrade() {
  var grade_inputs_form = document.getElementById("grade_inputs");
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var new_grade = '<div class="grade_input">Grade ' + gradeCounter+++': <input class="grade" type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="0"></div>';
  div.innerHTML = new_grade;
  var child = div.firstChild;
  grade_inputs_form.appendChild(child);

  displayGrade();
}

function removeGrade() {

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue
}
form {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 17pt;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button {
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-size: 14pt
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
div.grade_input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#buttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#grade_tag {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
#grade {
  margin-left: 6px;
  font-size: 36pt;
  color: #E60000;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #6A6A6A;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #6A6A6A;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #6A6A6A;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #6A6A6A;
}
```

```html
<h1>Student Grade Calculator</h1>

<div id="buttons">
  <button style="font-size: 24px;" onclick="addGrade()">Add Grade</button>
  <button style="font-size: 24px;" onclick="removeGrade()">Remove Grade</button>
</div>

<form id="grade_inputs" onkeyup="displayGrade()">
  <div class="grade_input">Grade 1:
    <input class="grade" type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="0">
  </div>
</form>

<span id="grade_tag">Average grade: </span>
<span id="grade">F</span>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/bfqaupod/2/)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, however it didn't work when I changed it. The "Add Grade" button doesn't add the element anymore. I pretty much copied your revision exactly :/

Comment: The only line that I see changed is 'div.appendChild(new_grade);' but when I change that in my own code, it still doesn't display when the button is clicked. Did you change something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is - **Id** is not same as **class**

```
var grade_label = document.getElementById("grade");

<input class="grade" type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" placeholder="0"></div>
```

you need to get element by `classname` rather than `id`.

Assuming that there will be multiple-grades of which you want to find out the average, then try

```
function displayGrade( )
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( "grade" );
    for ( var counter = 0; counter < elements.length; counter++ )
    {
       displayGradeForEach( elements[counter] );
    }
}

function displayGradeForEach( grade_label )
{
    var average = calculateAverage();

    var grade_letter;
    var grade_color;

    if(average < 70)
    {
        grade_letter = "F";
        grade_color = "#E60000";
    }
    else if(average < 80)
    {
        grade_letter = "C";
        grade_color = "#FF7700";
    }
    else if(average < 90)
    {
       grade_letter = "B";
       grade_color = "#FAC800";
    }
    else
    {
       grade_letter = "A";
       grade_color = "#5AE000";
    }

    grade_label.innerHTML = grade_letter;
    grade_label.style.color = grade_color;
}
```

Comment: Why would getting by classname vs ID cause the fields to reset?